# TypeScript: Type for event on hashchange

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

When I define `event` as type `HashChangeEvent`:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', (event: HashChangeEvent) => {
    const { target: { location: { hash } } } = event;

    /* ... */
});
```

I get TypeScript error:

```
TS2339: Property 'location' does not exist on type 'EventTarget | null'.
```

What kind of type I should specify to avoid the error?

Comment: try window.location

Comment: As per the specs, the event has no `location` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange Just new and old `URL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [to specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange#Using_an_event_handler), I should get a new `hash` value from the global object `location`:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
    const { location: { hash } } = window;

    /* ... */
});
```

Thank you!